# Methods to estimate one particular point of a function as much accurately as possible

Tags: regression, estimation

I have some data points $y_1,y_2,...,y_n$ which are decreasing with index number that is $y_1>y_2>...>y_n$. These points are coming from some perturbation of some unknown decreasing function $f$ which, if necessary, I can assume to be continuous. Now, I want to estimate the initial value of this function as accurately as possible i.e. $f(1)$ as accurately as possible. Is there a statistical method to do this?

You can think of a concrete example as follows (it does not fit my problem, though).

I have some data which can be considered to be perturbations of some known model, such as the geometric progression. That is, the $i$-th data point is a perturbation of $ar^{i-1}$. I know neither $a$ nor $r$.

My aim is to estimate $a$ as accurately as possible. Note, this means that instead of trying to model the whole data, I am trying to gain more information about one particular value, namely the first data point. So my aim currently is to estimate one particular point as accurately as possible.

This can be thought of as a particular example of giving maximum importance to estimating one particular value of a function, and we do not care about the other points as much as this one.

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: You seem to be asking to throw out data that are relevant to the estimation of $a$.  Moreover, it's not possible to evaluate possible estimators without knowing how your data might deviate from the model. Could you explain the first and elaborate on the second?

Comment: Kindly see the edited post.

Comment: Now your question is internally inconsistent: the concrete example permits an effective solution, as suggested by the reply by Aaron, but your general question cannot be addressed in that way.  Moreover, it's crucial that you describe (in either case) how the data can differ from this unknown $f$: what are the statistical properties of the deviations?

Comment: I thought the example illustrates the question. Sorry for the confusion. To honor Aaron's reply, I shall not delete the example. But the general question was that. See, it is not known how the data differ from the unknown $f$. Probably we have to assume a model.

Answer (score 1):

If you take the log of your data points $x_i$, you get:
$$\log(x_i) = \log (ar^{i-1})=\log a + (i-1)\log r$$
So it would be appropriate to fit $x_i$ with a linear model, with $(i-1)$ as the feature. The estimate of the intercept gives you the $\log(a)$ value.